# Angular UI-Grid Pivot

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have a collection of these Javascript objects: (Displayed as a DTO)

```
public class ParameterValueDTO : DataTransferObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public String Comments { get; set; }
  public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

By default, AngularJS UI-Grid will create a row for each ParameterValue object with 3 columns: Id, Comments, Description which works fine.

[IMAGE: Standard objects mapping to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lom5x.png)

What I would like to do however is create a column for each object's "Comments" value and bind it to the corresponding "Description" value.  Essentially pivoting the table so it only has 1 row (forget the ID column for now).

The javascript I've tried:

```
var cols = [];
var row = obj.data.ProductAttributes[0].Specifications[0].ParameterValues
var length = row.length;


for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cols.push({
        field: "Description",
        displayName: row[i].Comments
    });
}

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: cols,
    data: row
};
```

The above results in the following which is obviously wrong:

[IMAGE: One column, new row for each Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ4eM.png)

Is it possible to accomplish this with the current data structure or what exactly is the correct approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd modify the code to just reprocess your data.  ui-grid really only likes to bind to columns and rows, it can't reverse the order.

So you'd:

```
var pivotData = [ {} ];
data.forEach(function(parameterDTO) {
  pivotData[0][parameterDTO.comments] = parameterDTO.description;
});
```

Then you should be able to use that new data object as grid data.

Comment: could you please elaborate.