# Angular UI Grid change orientation to horizontal?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am not sure if I need to change the grid templates or if there is a regular way:

- I want a horizontal grid with 20 items.
- The grid dont need horizontal scrollig because the pagination is below.
- Each item should have the same fix size.
- Each item should have a top down order (and not left to right).

Its my first time with ui grid and I tried a bit but the result is "crap" :/ An working example will be so nice :)

Comment: whts the horizontal grid ? , and if u have more columns then if u give overflow the horizontal scroll will appear what you wants to achieve

Comment: I am not sure what u mean but if my grid is 1000px width, the grid just display 5 items each and each item is 200px width there is no problem. A grid without scrolling but a pagination to show each item.

Comment: Are you saying you want each record instance to be displayed as a column and not a row? If so, I think this may be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562670/angular-ui-grid-pivot

Comment: Hmm fine idea to transform the data. I think it is a bit dirty but maybe it works :)